# Efficiently count files in large tar archive

Tags: python, tar

I'm working on several large (~50 GB) `.tar.gz` files and need to count the number of files/objects contained in each.

I'm currently using

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
nfiles = len(tar.getnames())
```

to do so, but this approach is super slow. Are there more efficient methods to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe tar files have no central index, so the only way to find the number of files is to scan the whole thing.  Use a different file format.

Comment: Agreed: you end up having to read the whole 50G off the disk which is the problem you're likely running into.  Try this on the command line (bash or similar) and see if its faster.  Shouldn't be by much:  `tar tzf filenam.tar.gz | wc -l`  -- if that's slow too, then you're not likely to improve on it within python.